# Vectorize an sapply function

Tags: r, performance, vectorization

I am trying to vectorize the following function to drop the sapply loop. I am calculating cumulative skewness.

```r
cskewness <- function(.x) {
  skewness <- function(.x) {
    sqrt(length(.x)) * sum((.x - mean(.x))^3) / (sum((.x - mean(.x))^2)^(3 / 2))
  }
  sapply(seq_along(.x), function(k, z) skewness(z[1:k]), z = .x)
}
```

Not getting my algebra right. Have this which is wrong:

```r
skewness2 <- function(.x) {
  n <- length(.x)
  csum <- cumsum(.x)
  cmu <- csum / 1:length(.x)
  num <- cumsum(.x - cmu)^3
  den <- cumsum((.x - cmu)^2)^(3/2)
  sqrt(n) * num / den
}
```

Correct code produces:

```r
x <- c(1,2,4,5,8)

> cskewness(x)
[1]       NaN 0.0000000 0.3818018 0.0000000 0.4082483
> skewness2(x)
[1]      NaN 1.000000 1.930591 3.882748 4.928973
```

Comment: Hrmph. Cumulative sums with `^(3/2)` and cubed-differences, etc. I applaud the effort ...

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Higher-order_statistics) may be of interest.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using a single-pass `for` loop will be efficient:

```
cumskewness <- function(x) {
  n <- length(x)
  
  if (n == 0L) {
    return(x)
  } else if (n == 1L) {
    return(0)
  }
  
  m2 <- m3  <- term1 <- 0
  out <- numeric(n)
  out[1] <- NaN
  m1 <- x[1]
  
  for (i in 2:n) {
    n0 <- i - 1
    delta <- x[i] - m1
    delta_n <- delta/i
    m1 <- m1 + delta_n
    term1 <- delta*delta_n*n0
    m3 <- m3 + term1*delta_n*(n0 - 1) - 3*delta_n*m2
    m2 <- m2 + term1
    out[i] <- sqrt(i)*m3/m2^1.5
  }
  
  out
}
```

It is also straightforward to write up with `Rcpp`:

```
library(Rcpp)

cppFunction('
  NumericVector cumskewnessCpp(const NumericVector& x) {
    const int n = x.size();
    
    if (n == 0) {
      return(x);
    } else if (n == 1) {
      return(0);
    }
    
    int n1;
    double m1 = x(0);
    double m2, m3, delta, delta_n, term1;
    NumericVector out(n);
    out(0) = R_NaN;
    
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
      n1 = i + 1;
      delta = x(i) - m1;
      delta_n = delta/n1;
      m1 += delta_n;
      term1 = delta*delta_n*i;
      m3 += term1*delta_n*(i - 1) - 3*delta_n*m2;
      m2 += term1;
      out(i) = sqrt(n1)*m3/pow(m2, 1.5);
    }
    
    return out;
  }
')
```

### Testing

```
cumskewness(x)
#> [1] NaN 0.0000000 0.3818018 0.0000000 0.4082483
cumskewnessCpp(x)
#> [1] NaN  0.000000e+00  3.818018e-01 -2.808667e-17  4.082483e-01
```

### Benchmarking

Including the vectorized solution from @ThomisIsCoding:

```
cskewness_tic <- function(y) {
  # cumulative length of y
  k <- seq_along(y)
  # cumulative n-th order moments of y
  m3 <- cumsum(y^3)
  m2 <- cumsum(y^2)
  m1 <- cumsum(y)
  u <- m1 / k
  # expand cubic terms and refactor skewness in terms of num/den
  num <- (m3 - 3 * u * m2 + 3 * u^2 * m1 - k * u^3) / k
  den <- sqrt((m2 + k * u^2 - 2 * u * m1) / k)^3
  num / den
}

set.seed(0)
x <- sample(1e3)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  cskewness_tic = cskewness_tic(x),
  cumskewness = cumskewness(x),
  cumskewnessCpp = cumskewnessCpp(x),
  check = "equal",
  unit = "relative"
)
#> Unit: relative
#>            expr      min      lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
#>   cskewness_tic 2.035272 2.07954 2.006118 2.388216 2.282022 0.7228815   100
#>     cumskewness 3.930424 3.96835 4.003956 3.939762 3.711879 1.1339946   100
#>  cumskewnessCpp 1.000000 1.00000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.0000000   100
```

### A note of caution using `cskewness_tic`

Catastrophic cancellation can result in precision errors for higher-order moments. It occurs when the standard deviation is small relative to the mean. Demonstrating:

```
set.seed(0)
x <- sample(1e3) + 1e8

y1 <- cskewness(x)
y2 <- cumskewness(x)
y3 <- cumskewnessCpp(x)
y4 <- cskewness_tic(x); y4[1] <- NaN

all.equal(y1, y2)
#> [1] TRUE
all.equal(y1, y3)
#> [1] TRUE
all.equal(y1, y4)
#> [1] "Mean relative difference: 270.1872"
```

### Original Answer

```
skewness2 <- function(.x) {
  d <- outer(.x, cumsum(.x)/(1:length(.x)), "-")
  d[lower.tri(d)] <- 0
  sqrt(1:length(.x))*colSums(d^3)/colSums(d^2)^(3/2)
}

x <- c(1,2,4,5,8)
cskewness(x)
#> [1]       NaN 0.0000000 0.3818018 0.0000000 0.4082483
skewness2(x)
#> [1]       NaN 0.0000000 0.3818018 0.0000000 0.4082483
```

Comment: Truly impressive, jblood94!

Comment: good approach, +1, but I think `outer` is the bottleneck for both memory-wise and time-wise efficiency.

Answer (score 9):

## Update

Thanks for [jblood94's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77767245/12158757) effort to capture the possible hazard caused by significant outliers, I have opportunity to rethink and optimize the code.

We can use `scale` to pre-process the input vector, such that the detrimental impacts by the outliers are minimized, and also the skewness is not affected as well

```
cskewness_tic <- function(y) {
    # rescale `y` to avoid detrimental impacts by outliers
    y <- scale(y)
    # cumulative length of y
    k <- seq_along(y)
    # cumulative n-th raw moments of y
    m3 <- cumsum(y^3)
    m2 <- cumsum(y^2)
    m1 <- cumsum(y)
    u <- m1 / k
    # expand cubic terms and refactor skewness in terms of num/den
    num <- (m3 - 3 * u * m2 + 3 * u^2 * m1 - k * u^3) / k
    den <- sqrt((m2 + k * u^2 - 2 * u * m1) / k)^3
    c(NaN, (num / den)[-1])
}
```

## Benchmark

With list of functions for benchmarking (see details of `cumskewness` and `cumskewnessCpp` from [@jblood94's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77767245/12158757))

```
set.seed(0)
x <- sample(1e6) + 1e10
microbenchmark(
    cskewness_tic = cskewness_tic(x),
    cumskewness = cumskewness(x),
    cumskewnessCpp = cumskewnessCpp(x),
    check = "equal",
    unit = "relative",
    times = 50L
)
```

shows

```
Unit: relative
           expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
  cskewness_tic 3.144719 3.268279 3.461112 3.314326 3.846614 2.395820    50
    cumskewness 4.647973 4.627621 4.455523 4.585634 4.448119 2.687571    50
 cumskewnessCpp 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000    50
```

## Previous Solution

First of all, non-vectorized approaches are not as bad as you think, so `*apply` is also a good option if you think it fits your ultimate objective and simplifies your work. No need face the loops with a fear.

---

If you want to take benefits from vectorization (like speed), you can try expanding the mathematical expression of skewness in terms of raw moments (refer [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_(mathematics))), and then have `cumsum` operations on each decoupled term

```
cskewness_tic <- function(y) {
    # cumulative length of y
    k <- seq_along(y)
    # cumulative n-th raw moments of y
    m3 <- cumsum(y^3)
    m2 <- cumsum(y^2)
    m1 <- cumsum(y)
    u <- m1 / k
    # expand cubic terms and refactor skewness in terms of num/den
    num <- (m3 - 3 * u * m2 + 3 * u^2 * m1 - k * u^3) / k
    den <- sqrt((m2 + k * u^2 - 2 * u * m1) / k)^3
    num / den
}
```

such that

```
> cskewness_tic(x)
[1]       NaN 0.0000000 0.3818018 0.0000000 0.4082483
```

## benchmark

List of apporaches

```
cskewness_origin <- function(.x) {
    skewness <- function(.x) {
        sqrt(length(.x)) * sum((.x - mean(.x))^3) / (sum((.x - mean(.x))^2)^(3 / 2))
    }
    sapply(seq_along(.x), function(k, z) skewness(z[1:k]), z = .x)
}

cskewness_jblood94 <- function(.x) {
    d <- outer(.x, cumsum(.x) / (1:length(.x)), "-")
    d[lower.tri(d)] <- 0
    sqrt(1:length(.x)) * colSums(d^3) / colSums(d^2)^(3 / 2)
}

cskewness_tic <- function(y) {
    # cumulative length of y
    k <- seq_along(y)
    # cumulative n-th order moments of y
    m3 <- cumsum(y^3)
    m2 <- cumsum(y^2)
    m1 <- cumsum(y)
    u <- m1 / k
    # expand cubic terms and refactor skewness in terms of num/den
    num <- (m3 - 3 * u * m2 + 3 * u^2 * m1 - k * u^3) / k
    den <- sqrt((m2 + k * u^2 - 2 * u * m1) / k)^3
    num / den
}
```

by running the following benchmarking

```
set.seed(0)
x <- sample(1e3)
microbenchmark(
    origin = cskewness_origin(x),
    jblood94 = cskewness_jblood94(x),
    tic = cskewness_tic(x),
    unit = "relative",
    check = "equivalent",
    times = 50L
)
```

we see

```
Unit: relative
     expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
   origin 252.7504 247.1442 253.5965 254.8663 257.2905 239.0963    50
 jblood94 302.8267 309.0854 326.7546 318.7141 310.2365 388.3786    50
      tic   1.0000   1.0000   1.0000   1.0000   1.0000   1.0000    50
```

Comment: Side note: You calculate `cumsum(y)` twice.

Comment: @Friede aha, nice catch! now it is fixed.

Comment: Very clever expanding the terms, +1! You may want to do something like `y <- y - y[1]` up front in order to avoid catastrophic cancellation. See my updated answer.

Comment: @jblood94 yes and thank you for pointing out that hazard caused by a significant outlier. Your `for` loop solution looks great and stable, I really wish I am able to give you a second +1!

Comment: I am not afraid of the *apply, it just gets slow with large vectors and thank you for the efforts

Comment: @MCP_infiltrator haha, that's great you don't treat `*apply` as a monster :P. Also, I updated my solution to fix the bug, so you can try it as well.

Comment: @jblood94 I think `scale` can be used to pre-process the raw data before my `cumsum` operations in `cskewness_tic`,  please see my updates

Comment: I use *apply a lot especially lapply they are great tools